# regular expression to match strings with decimals

Tags: regex, string, perl

I'm trying to create a regex which will do the following:

```
Name description:  "QUARTERLY PATCH FOR XAQE (JUL 2013 - 11.2.0.3.20) : (125546467)"
Val version    : 11.2.0.3.4
```

In order to output:

```
"Name, 11.2.0.3.20"
"Val, 11.2.0.3.4"
```

I have created the following regex: `/^([\w]+).*([\d\.\d]+).*/`, but it is only matching the last number in the 2nd group, i.e. in `11.2.0.3.4` it will only match `4`. Could anyone help?

Also, there could be more than the two lines given above, so it needs to account for arbitrary lines where the version number could be anywhere in the line.

Comment: How did `11.2.0.3.20` transform to `11.2.0.3.21` in the output?

Comment: @OGHaza oh, ok.  I thought by black magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a one-liner for this as well:

```
perl -lne '/(\w+).*?(\d+(\.\d+)+)/; print "$1, $2"' <filename>

__END__
Name, 11.2.0.3.20
Val, 11.2.0.3.4
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only planning for the output and not doing any processing over the captured groups, then this will do:

```
$str =~ s/([\n\r]|^)(Name|Val).*?(\d+(\.\d+)+).*/$1"$2, $3"/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `.*` is greedy and will consume as much as it can whilst the pattern still matches. One solution is to make is lazy `.*?`

Also `[\d\.\d]+` means match one of `\d`, `\.` and `\d`, so it's the same as `[\d.]+` which isn't what you want since it would match "2013" in the first line. `\d+(\.\d+)+` is more suitable.

After those 2 changes you have:

```
^([\w]+).*?(\d+(\.\d+)+).*
```

[RegExr](http://regexr.com?38gmt)

Comment: That doesn't work, as `([.\d]+)` will match any number

Comment: @AkshaiShah Yeah sorry, I misread the problem in the question, when you said 2nd group I thought you meant the problem was only in the 2nd line. Note that your original regex matches any number too.

Comment: `([\w]+)` is no different than `(\w+)`

Comment: I'm aware, I was just fixing the problems